# Homomorphism from Positive Integers onto Odd Positive Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that there exists a homomorphism of the multiplicative semigroup of the positive integers onto the multiplicative semigroup of odd positive integers.

One example would be helpful.
[Edit: This homomorphism does not need to be injective, only surjective]

Comment: Hint: Consider the odd part of $n$ (all factors of $2$ removed).
$$$$
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPart.html
$$$$